# How to read CSV file data in ansible-playbook using with_lines?

Tags: loops, variables, ansible, ansible-2.x

I have situation where in one csv file i have 2 columns like below

```
cat report.csv
Field1,Field2,Field3
name3,3,5
name4,5,6
```

now i want to use the lines which are in bold.

Each column will be an input to one of the ansible role.

it should go like

```
   roles:
     - { role: arti_master, mod_name: "{{ item.name}}" , version: "{{ item.version}}"
  with_lines:
    - "cat report.csv|cut -d, -f2"
```

Answer (score 2):

Here is an example:

```
- name: "Sending email"
  hosts: localhost
  gather_facts: no
  tasks:
  - name: "Reading user information"
    read_csv:
      path: users.csv
    register: users
  - name: "Sending an e-mail using Gmail SMTP servers"
    mail:
      host: smtp.gmail.com
      port: 587
      username: <email>
      password: <pass>
      to: "{{ user.email }}"
      subject: Email Subjet
      body: |
        Hi {{ user.first_name }},

        How are you? 
    loop: "{{ users.list }}"
    loop_control:
      loop_var: user
```

And the CSV:

```
first_name,last_name,email
Joel,Zamboni,joel.zamboni@example.com
```

The `read_csv` returns the data in two formats, as a `dict` or as a `list` and in this case I am 'looping' over the list to send emails.

Best,

Joel

Answer (score 1):

I believe you have two (and a half) ways that I can think of:

1. Do as you said and run the file through `cut` or `python -c "import csv;..."` or other "manual" processing, then capture the output in a variable

   Anything that looks like JSON when fed into a `vars:` or `set_fact:` will become a `list` or `dict`, so you'd just want the text to go into a tool looking like CSV and come out of the tool looking like JSON
2. Use the [`lookup("csvfile")`](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/2.7/plugins/lookup/csvfile.html) to actually read the file using an "approved" mechanism

   1. *(this is the "half" part:)* if the csv is on the remote machine, then use `fetch:` to pull it to your controlling machine, *then* run `lookup("csvfile")` on it

Comment: Better will be to write a ansible customized module using python and Ansible Module to do this operation.

Answer (score 0):

[read_csv](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/devel/modules/read_csv_module.html) module was recently added to ansible, and is now available from ansible 2.8. After upgrading ansible, you can read line by line as follows:

```
  - name: read the csv file
    read_csv:
      path: "{{ report.csv }}"
      delimiter: ','
    register: report_csv
```

You can then access it as list by using `report_csv.list` and it'll hold values as a list of dictionaries:

```
[{'Field1': 'name3', 'Field2': 3, 'Field3': 5}, {'Field1': 'name4', 'Field2': 5, 'Field3': 6}]
```

Comment: https://github.com/kunaljha5/using_custom_module_in_ansible/blob/master/library/dictinary_compare.py

Answer (score 0):

Sharing my ansible code as well  this is what worked for me https://stackoverflow.com/a/56910479/1679541

playbook.yaml

```
---
- name: Read Users
  gather_facts: True
  hosts: localhost

  tasks:
  - read_csv:
      path: users.csv
    register: userlist

  - debug: 
      msg: "{{ user.username }} and password is {{ user.password }}"
    loop: "{{ userlist.list }}"
    loop_control:
      loop_var: user
```

users.csv

```
username,password
user0,test123
user1,test123
```

Ansible Output

```sh
PLAY [Read Users] *************************************************

TASK [Gathering Facts] *********************************************************
ok: [127.0.0.1]

TASK [read_csv] ****************************************************************
ok: [127.0.0.1]

TASK [debug] *******************************************************************
ok: [127.0.0.1] => (item={u'username': u'user0', u'password': u'test123'}) => {
    "msg": "user0 and password is test123"
}
ok: [127.0.0.1] => (item={u'username': u'user1', u'password': u'test123'}) => {
    "msg": "user1 and password is test123"
}

PLAY RECAP *********************************************************************
127.0.0.1                  : ok=3    changed=0    unreachable=0    failed=0    skipped=0    rescued=0    ignored=0
```