# Not able to read/print the csv file data

Tags: ansible

Running the below playbook and trying to print the value of that task. It fails with below error.

> FAILED! => {"msg": "The task includes an option with an undefined variable. The error was: 'list object' has no attribute 'name'\n\nThe error appears to be in '/Users/srikanth.venugopalan/ansible/roles/rmi_staging/tasks/main.yml': line 9, column 4, but may\nbe elsewhere in the file depending on the exact syntax problem.\n\nThe offending line appears to be:\n\n   register: topics\n - debug:\n   ^ here\n"

The code is

```
 - name: Login to cluster
   shell: /home/srikanth/ls.sh
 - name: Read the CSV file
   read_csv:
     path: /home/srikanth/template1.csv
   register: topics
 - debug:
     msg: 'Name {{ topics.list.name }}'
```

I have tried below as well, but no luck

```
 - name: Login to cluster
   shell: /home/srikanth/ls.sh
 - name: Read the CSV file
   read_csv:
     path: /home/srikanth/template1.csv
   register: topics
 - debug:
     msg: 'Name {{ topics.list.1.name }}'
```

`CSV` file format as per below

```
name,replica,partition
test-topic,3,3
```

I have gone through the link [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53799730/how-to-read-csv-file-data-in-ansible-playbook-using-with-lines](https://www.stackoverflow.com/), but one thing dont know in the `debug` how it come `user.username`.

Please guide me.

Actual goal is to take name alone from the `debug` output.

Comment: I wonder about your first task. You run the playbook on the remote host, you do not need to login. And later you can check the registered variable with debug module and var: topics .

Answer (score 1):

Your `.1.name` attempt didn't work because `topics.list` is, like all list data structures in python, 0-indexed

You can observe the behavior for yourself, as the comments asked you to:

```yaml
  tasks:
  - copy:
      dest: ./template1.csv
      content: |
        name,replica,partition
        test-topic,3,3
  - read_csv:
      path: ./template1.csv
    register: topics
  - debug:
      var: topics
  - debug:
      msg: 'Name {{ topics.list.0.name }}'
```

emits

```
ok: [localhost] => {
    "topics": {
        "changed": false,
        "dict": {},
        "failed": false,
        "list": [
            {
                "name": "test-topic",
                "partition": "3",
                "replica": "3"
            }
        ]
    }
}
ok: [localhost] => {
    "msg": "Name test-topic"
}
```